# win32 api for Python only lets me see new data after calling the ReadFile() function. Is there any method to see past that?

Tags: python, winapi

My aim is to make message reading from a socket completely nonblocking, so that I can instantly return a `None` if the message hasn't been sent completely or if there's no new message. I have a file I created in order to listen to a pipe like this:

```
def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
    self.handle = win32file.CreateFile(
        name,
        win32file.GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        None,
        win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        None
        )
```

This file receives first number of bytes to be read, and that length takes 4 bytes, and then the bytes themselves. In order to see how many bytes are in the file, there's `win32file.GetFileSize()` and, if I want to see what bytes have been written, I found `win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe()` which seems to work fine. However, these methods seem to be affected by some kind of terminator inside the file after each message and this happens:

```
#the 4 bytes keeping the length of the message and the message itself have already been written to the file
buffer = win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(self.handle, 1000)[0]
print(str(buffer)) #only prints 4 bytes

length = struct.unpack('i', self.ReadFile(self.handle, 4))[0] #read 4 bytes and calculate the length

buffer = win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(self.handle, length)[0]
print(str(buffer)) #prints the whole message
```

Basically, only after calling `win32file.ReadFile(self.handle, 4)` will `win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe()` and `win32file.GetFileSize()` acknowledge that there's more inside the file than those 4 bytes. Is this a known behaviour? If so, is there any way that I can Peek through both the length and the message in order to know when the message is ready? I have no access to the socket that's writing through this pipe though, but I know for sure that it's sending messages like how I described earlier (message size + message).

Comment: What is the value of `length`? Can you show the complete code sample?

Comment: `PeekNamedPipe` copies data from a named or anonymous pipe into a buffer without removing it from the pipe. This is not a known behavior, and at least it cannot be reproduced in C++.